# How can I make media keys work with i3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, i3

I've moved from Gnome to i3 on Manjaro, and I'm almost done with configuring the window manager, and terminal colors and whatnot. After some time I just decided to listen to some music, and after a couple of minutes I realized that the volume keys and playback keys don't work.

I have a Razer Blackwidow Stealth 2014 keyboard, so those media keys are actually together with the Function keys. For example: Play/Pause is on <kbd>F6</kbd>, and it acts as a media key when I press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, like in <kbd>Fn + F6</kbd>.

Comment: I tried to clean up this question because frankly about 90% of it was just *wrong*. Now it's fine, and you're answer clears it up. Two of the very things you had your answer prev/next were exactly in your answer. The only real improvement in was moving play to play/pause (which makes no difference to whether or not it works at all). Moreover, the `xev` command was totally bunk. If that was the output of xev when you hit those keys your answer would work. Try it again. Your state should say something `XF86AudioNext` and the like.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## The search for the answer

After some time messing around with the controls, I've found a post on the old i3 FAQ board: https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3747/enabling-multimedia-keys.1.html

It says to paste the following into i3's .config file (bellow is a lightly modified version, with some lines removed, which are not relevant to this particular question):

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 -5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle # mute sound

# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness

# Media player controls
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioPause exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous
```

And it didn't work either, however the process of finding the answer is correct.

## The real answer

To me, at least, the problem was that after copying those lines, the keys would not work. After some more research, I found out that the volume commands could be a little different, using `amixer` instead of PulseAudio's `pactl`.

At the end, those were left like this:

```
# Media volume controls
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer sset 'Master' toggle
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer sset 'Master' 5%-
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer sset 'Master' 5%+
```

and they started working.

The playback keys were a little more trickier. I deduced that the .config tells which *command* is executed to do the action. Then I proceeded to try `playerctl play-pause` on my terminal. Of course it didn't work, because **playerctl was not installed**. After installing it (using `sudo pacman -S playerctl`) those keyboard commands worked just fine too.

Comment: For the volume control, the first way worked for me by changing the sinks to 1 instead of 0. You can see your sinks by doing pactl list | grep sink

Comment: You can use `amixer -D pulse set 'Master' 1+ toggle` to mute / unmute all the required channels.

Answer (score 5):

I found that I needed a `--` to separate the `pactl` from the `set-sink-...` and that it was more consistent to use `@DEFAULT_SINK@` if you use headphones.

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl -- set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle # mute sound
```

Comment: +1 for @DEFAULT_SINK@. For me, the two dashes were not required, they even prevent this from working (mxLinux here).

Answer (score 2):

I just replaced 0 with one. Example:

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 1 +5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 1 -5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 1 toggle # mute sound
```

To see what number is for your audio device open `pavucontrol` and click output devices the top one is 0 under that is one, etc.